# How to handle multi select list box using selenium?

Tags: selenium, listbox, multi-select

Help me with selenium commands/code to fetch the data from the list. We can only select the data from the list, since entering text(like auto search) is not allowed.

[image]

I have used the following code, but couldn't resolve the issue. Also I have doubt regarding which xpath given Do I need to give the xpath of the input field or the drop down list?

```
    *WebElement mySelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='basicBootstrapForm']/div[7]/div/multi-select"));
    Select dropdown= new Select(mySelectElement);
        dropdown.selectByValue("Arabic");
        dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Catalan");*
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: @SudhaThangavel Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to first click on the dropdwon box and then find out the elemnet you are looking for and then click.Hope this help you.Let me know if this work

```
driver.findElement(By.id("msdd")).click();
        List<WebElement> languages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='ui-corner-all']"));
        for(int i=0;i<languages.size();i++)
          {
            System.out.println(languages.get(i).getText());
            if(languages.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Arabic"))
            {
                languages.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
          }
```

Comment: Thanks Kajal. It was very helpful. What if I need to select multiple values say Arabic, Dutch and English from the list?